# Data model code running too slowly

Tags: performance, r, stan

The model takes a long time to run. I have tried to vectorise it as far as I can, but it's still taking about a day to compute. I'm wondering if it's possible to speed it up.

Maybe the problem isn't even with the code, but with the model being improper/bad priors/...? Or maybe the data set is simply very large and supposed to take hours to compute. Either way, for now, I dread adding another predictor.

```
# data is in wide format, one row with one outcome and a range of predictors

set_cppo(mode = "fast")

code ="                     // the model itself
data        {
       int<lower=1> nrow;   // 72000 (3 items per W*N*R)
       int W;               // n words; 24
       int N;               // n subjects; 100
       int R;               // n raters; 10
       int<lower=1,upper=nrow> ind[nrow]; // this vector is used to index fields per row
       int<lower=0,upper=1> responses[nrow];  // outcomes
       int subjects[nrow];
       int words[nrow];
       int sex[nrow];
       int languages[nrow];
       int raters[nrow];
}

parameters  {
real intercept;               // "fixed"
real beta_language;
real beta_sex;
real interaction_s_l;
real beta_rater[R];           // "random"
real beta_word[W];
real beta_subject[N];
} 

model       {
real theta[nrow];

 beta_word ~ normal(0,100);         // priors
 beta_subject ~ normal(0,100);
 beta_language ~ normal(0,100);
 beta_sex ~ normal(0,100);
 interaction_s_l ~ normal(0,100);


for (i in 1:nrow){                    // for each row, construct theta
theta[i] <- intercept
          + beta_sex * sex[ind[i]]
          + beta_language * languages[ind[i]]
          + interaction_s_l * languages[ind[i]] * sex[ind[i]]
          + beta_subject[subjects[ind[i]]]
          + beta_rater[raters[ind[i]]];}

responses ~ bernoulli_logit(theta);   // sample
}

generated quantities {               // get odds ratios
real odds_intercept;
real odds_sex;
real odds_language;
real odds_interaction;

odds_intercept <- exp(intercept);
odds_sex <- exp(beta_sex);
odds_language <- exp(beta_language);
odds_interaction <- exp(interaction_s_l);
}
"


fit <- stan(model_code = code, data = dat,     // run the model
            iter = 4000, chains = 3)
```

Comment: Could you describe the purpose of this code?

Comment: It's supposed to estimate the odds ratios for my predictors, with "sex" and "language" as well as their interaction as 'fixed' and "word" and "subject" as 'random' effects. Does it not do that? I have added some comments.

Comment: Oh no, I'm asking because it'll help give a more descriptive title.  You may make that change now.

Comment: This is a bit late, but I'd suggest taking a look on the Stan-users mailing list where these kinds of questions get asked daily.

Comment: I happened to come across this again and finally got to take a look at it. One easy transformation you can do is use *standard* normal priors, which you then rescale in the `transformed parameters` block. e.g. `transformed parameters{ beta_word <- beta_word_standardized * 10; }` then `model { beta_word_standardized ~ normal(0,1); }`.

Comment: Also note that there is a paper by Gelman et al on the subject of prior selection Bayesian logistic regression, albeit without mention of random effects. "We recommend using, as a default prior model, independent Cauchy distributions on all logistic regression coefficients, each centered at 0 and with scale parameter 10 for the constant term and 2.5 for all other coefficients. Before fitting this model, we center each binary input to have mean 0 and rescale each numeric input to have mean 0 and standard deviation 0.5." http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/priors11.pdf

Comment: For posterity, that's Gelman, Jakulin, Grazia Pittau, and Su. (2006). A weakly informative default prior distribution for logistic and other regression models.

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo. The line

```
responses ~ bernoulli_logit(theta);
```

should be outside the `for` loop in the `model` block.